# wordpress add action not working with Ninja Forms

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms

I am new to wordpress. I am trying to implement custom css onto NinjaForms. No matter what I do the form styling does not change. If I type the CSS in a live CSS editor all works fine. I have added the following code to a custom plugin in my wordpress site.

```
function action_ninja_forms_display_css( $form_id ) { 
    if( $form_id == 22 ) {
        echo '<style>
        .ninja-forms-form-wrap{background:red}
        </style>';
    }
}; 
     
add_action( 'ninja_forms_display_css', 'action_ninja_forms_display_css' )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you forgot to add semicolon (`;`) after `add_action()`

Comment: Thanks. Was an omission in my submission. Double checked and still the same result.

Comment: hook seems to be deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello try This Code**

```
function action_ninja_forms_display_css( $form_id ) { 
    if( $form_id == 22 ) {
        echo '<style>
        .ninja-forms-form-wrap{background:red}
        </style>';
    }
}; 
   
add_action( 'ninja_forms_display_css', 'action_ninja_forms_display_css', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks. Gave this ago and still nothing changes.